# Why do I get this error when I compile my MySQL connection test?

Tags: mysql, c, linux

`fcts_mysql.h`:

```
MYSQL * cmd_mysql_init();
```

`fcts_mysql.c`:

```
#include "fcts_mysql.h"
MYSQL *cmd_mysql_init(){
  return mysql_init(NULL);
}
```

`mysql_test.c`:

```
#include "../lib/fcts_mysql.h"

#include <mysql.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    MYSQL *cnxion;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;


    char *server   = "192.168.1.2";
    char *user     = "root";
    char *password = ""; 
    char *database = "test";

//  cnxion = mysql_init(NULL);     

    cnxion = cmd_mysql_init();

    if (!mysql_real_connect(cnxion, server,user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n 404 \n", mysql_error(cnxion));return 1;
    }

    if (mysql_query(cnxion, "show tables")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(cnxion));return 1;
    }
    res = mysql_use_result(cnxion);  

//  res    = cmd_mysql_select();

    printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
//  FILE *file = fopen("liste_table.txt","w");
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL){
    //  printf("%s \n", row[0]);fprintf(file,"%s \n",row[0]);
    }
//  fclose(file);   
    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(cnxion);

    return 0 ;
}
```

```
[root@xxxxx bin]# gcc  mysql_test.c $(mysql_config --libs) $(mysql_config --cflags)
In file included from mysql_test.c:1:
../lib/fcts_mysql.h:6: erreur: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

Comment: `MYSQL` isn't defined in  `fcts_mysql.h`. You should probably include a header first.

Comment: thnx @Biffen for your help but i try to add it and after i get the error like :    /tmp/ccAvihja.o: In function `main':
/root/projet/test/bin/mysql_test.c:21: undefined reference to `cmd_mysql_init'
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution

Comment: That's a *linking* error. It looks like you're not linking your binary with the (or a) MySQL library.

Comment: i dont think so , because i use gcc  mysql_test.c $(mysql_config --libs) $(mysql_config --cflags) to compile ... if you now other methde to link it plz let me know .. thanks la lot .

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about your setup. Maybe you should look into a build system that takes care of all that stuff for you, instead of running the commands manually.

Comment: now i get error like : reference indefine to my fonction cmd_mysql_init()

Comment: Are you linking *all* your compiled objects?

Answer (score 0):

`MYSQL` is not known to the compiler when it get to it in `"../lib/fcts_mysql.h"`.

Moving `#include <mysql.h>`  in front of `#include "../lib/fcts_mysql.h"` will fix the issue.

Comment: It's better to have `fcts_mysql.h` include all its needed headers itself.